# Why can't I use DOM element as prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and would appreciate help in understanding why the following won't work.
Here is the HTML:

```
<canvas id="MyCanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
MyCanvas = function (bar) {
    this.foo = bar;
}

MyCanvas.prototype = document.getElementById('MyCanvas');

var c = new MyCanvas(20);

alert(c.id);
```

I would have expected that 'MyCanvas' gets alerted, as I set the prototype to an object where the id attribute has that value. You can check the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2V9KQ/2/

Comment: Uhm, it alerts `MyCanvas` for me ?

Comment: Ditto. Works for me in Chrome

Comment: Works in Chrome, but not in Firefox (`TypeError: Value does not implement interface Element.` in the `alert(c.id);` line); haven't tested others.

Comment: `TypeError: 'id' getter called on an object that does not implement interface Element.`

Comment: It's very strange to set up a prototype from specific element. Prototypes are usually used for things that are instantiated multiple times.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` in Safari: `Deprecated attempt to access property 'id' on a non-Element object.`

Comment: The problem with that is that all your instances will point to MyCanvas (in browsers that support it).Create 2 instances and change the id of one,the other will have the same id.Is it what you want? It's usually not a good idea to try to extend the DOM,there are a lot of internal stuff going on(property descriptors,private constructors...) and of course it depends on the browser implementatin of the DOM,something one cannot control.

Comment: This is not the typical way to use prototypes. Not sure if you have some use case that demands this approach, but it is definitely not the standard way to extend native DOM elements. Also worth mentioning... many developers shun the practice of extending objects you don't own. A great example of why not can be found in MooTools. They had a `bind` method with they added to the Function prototype. EMAC implemented a `bind` method in the standard, and now MooTools was interfering with standardized behavior. If you ARE going to extend native object prototypes, this is not how it is done.

Comment: It is also not very clear what you want to accomplish here. What would the argument do, exactly? What if you created 3 instances of the MyCanvas object with different constructor arguments, would they all reference the same DomElement? I am guessing here, but it looks like you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job. Since the job isn't defined, it is hard to respond with any more specific input.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, the plan was to somehow extend this specific DOM element. However, I posted the question in order to get a better understanding of JavaScript, DOM and prototypes. I still don't get why this won't work in FF though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the canvas doesn't have an own `id` property:

```
// Setup
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.id = "MyCanvas";
// Tests
c.hasOwnProperty('id'); // false
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('id'); // false
HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('id'); // false
Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('id'); // true
```

Basically, what happens is that `id` property is only defined in `Element.prototype`, and it has a getter and a setter. When you set or get it, the information is stored in or read from an internal property of that `Element` instance.

But here you are using the property `id` on a instance of `MyCanvas` which isn't a true element (although it is an instance of `Element`). Then, the getter and setter of `Element.prototype.id` don't work.